# Beamer: set mode mid-presentation

Tags: beamer

In Beamer, is it possible to switch between handout mode and presentation mode in the middle of a presentation?

The reason I want to do this is that I am working through a slide deck in multiple lectures.  I want to omit the pauses for slides from previous lectures to support quickly navigating to them for reference (handout mode), while for the current lecture I would like to include the pauses for presentation purposes (presentation mode).

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Step 1 \pause Step 2 \pause Step 3
\end{frame}

% I want to switch to presentation mode here!

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Step 4 \pause Step 5 \pause Step 6
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After compiling, I would like to have four slides.  One slide showing the entire Frame 1, and three slides showing the three stages of Frame 2.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`beamer` holds the selected mode in the macro `\beamer@currentmode` so what you need to do is change that mid-way through your document.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,handout]{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91691/86}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\changemode[1]{%
  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Step 1 \pause Step 2 \pause Step 3
\end{frame}

% I want to switch to presentation mode here!
\changemode{beamer}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Step 4 \pause Step 5 \pause Step 6
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, there may be things "under the bonnet" which depend on the mode during initialisation so it might be that you want to start in `beamer` mode, switch to `handout` (or maybe `trans`) at the start of the slides, then back to `beamer` for the slides for the current lecture.

Comment: Thank you!  I assumed there was a macro that stored this setting, but I couldn't find it in the documentation or with a google search.  As you recommended, I begin in `beamer` mode, switch to `handout` mode at the beginning, then switch back to `beamer` mode midway through the presentation.  It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @walkie I did a grep through the code and couldn't find such a macro.  I guess it's one of those "here be dragons" in that things *could* go wrong if you weren't careful.

Comment: Just a note: setting the macro apparently does only work after `\begin{document}` (please don't ask why I need to change it within the header but after the document class :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work the second time, only the first...